# Swift: Implementing Comparable with computed struct property

Tags: swift, computed-properties

I'm trying to implement comparable on a struct Pitch, that has a computed property called value. The computed property is marked 'mutating get' as it needs to modify this instance property. But when I try and extend so as to make the struct comparable, I get an error next to the return line saying:

*Cannot use mutating getter on immutable value: 'lhs' is a 'let' constant*

```
  extension Pitch: Comparable {
    public static func < (lhs: Pitch, rhs: Pitch) -> Bool {
        return lhs.value < rhs.value
    }
```

Any idea how to fix this please?

Comment: *Why* is the getter mutating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mainly Because Mutating is changing the value of a variable inside the Object.

```
lhs & rhs  // Are parameter.
```

And parameter are immutable (Constants) in Swift.

Therefore you can clone those Parameters into new Objects of Type `var` and use their mutable `Value`.

And because they're of type `Struct` **Value Type** you can simply say this `var newObj = myOldObj`.

Your code could be something like this.

```
public static func < (lhs: Pitch, rhs: Pitch) -> Bool {
    var lhsObj = lhs
    var rhsObj = rhs
    return lhsObj.value < rhsObj.value
}
```

Comment: `lhs` and `rhs` are of type `Pitch`

Comment: @Carpsen90 edited thanks :D didnt notice when i reproduced the case

Comment: Thanks Tobi - that works. Presumably it should be fairly efficient creating new new objs as they're structs.